# Get distinct file path

Tags: c#

For example, I have folder structure like this:

Drive C:
|-- Global
|------Folder
|------|----FileA.dll
|------|----FileB.dll
|------|----FileA_1.dll
|------CodeFolder
|------|----FildeCode.dll
|------|----FildeCode_1.dll
|------ContentFolder
|------|----ScriptsFolder
|------|--------FileScripts.dll
|------|--------FileScriptsA.dll
|------|--------FileScripts_1.dll

I want to get list file path, but each of file is unique and distinct:

Here the result (*order in here is ignored*):
C:\Global\Folder\FileA_1.dll
C:\Global\Folder\FileB.dll
C:\Global\CodeFolder\FileCode_1.dll
C:\Global\ContentFolder\ScriptFolder\FileScriptsA.dll
C:\Global\ContentFolder\ScriptFolder\FileScripts_1.dll

How do I do by C#?

Comment: Every file with `_<number>` suffix wins over file without suffix? What if you have `FileA.dll`, `FileA_1.dll`, `FileA_1_1.dll`, `FileA_2.dll`?

Comment: I will take the last file. In your case is: FileA_2.dll

Comment: Do you need only "*.dll" files?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: yes, I just need dll file only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need natural sort for file name ordering, so you can import StrCmpLogicalW function. You have to enable unsafe code for your project.

```
internal sealed class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);

    public static readonly NaturalStringComparer Default = new NaturalStringComparer();

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }
}
```

Then you can get the list of files using the following code.

```
string[] filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Global\", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                 .Select(path => new
                                 {
                                     Path = path,
                                     Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
                                     TruncatedName = Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileName(path), @"(_\d+)+(?=\.dll$)", string.Empty)
                                 })
                                 .GroupBy(file => file.TruncatedName)
                                 .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(file => file.Name, NaturalStringComparer.Default).First().Path)
                                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: If I remove NaturalStringComparer.Default in OrderByDescending, it work like expected. Do you need it?

Comment: @TPL Yes, you need. Imagine if you have 'File_1.dll', 'File_2.dll', 'File_12.dll'. You would need 'File_12.dll', but simple order will return 'File_2.dll' for you.

Comment: I will get the File_2.dll because File_1 is old

Comment: @TPL I'm talking about `File_12.dll`, it is newer than `File_2.dll`. If you have only 1-digit suffices, you don't need natural string comparer.

Answer (score 1):

why don't  you do it like this (or am i missing something here)

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetFiles("directoryPath", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```